# Remove an element from an array in JavaScript with slice or spread

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have been watching the video on redux from Dan Abramov [avoiding-array-mutations](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-avoiding-array-mutations-with-concat-slice-and-spread) and I have worked out how to use `slice` to remove an element from an array by id, returning the new array without mutation.

```
var arrayOld = ['apple', 'orange', 'fig']
var index = arrayOld.indexOf('orange')
var arrayNew = arrayOld.slice(0,index).concat(arrayOld.slice(index + 1))
// ['apple', 'fig']
```

I was wondering how I would do the same using `es6 spread` syntax?

Also I am wondering why there is not a simpler way: e.g. a helper function in es6 to do this, something that works as simply as the concat method, where you could just pass in the id of the element to remove and it returns the new array, so basically splice but without the mutation.

Comment: `[...arr]` is the same as `arr.slice()`, you could "slice and splice" for no side effects removal

Comment: in the video he show you this way of doing it with array spread ```[...arrayOld.slice(0,index), ...arrayOld.slice(index+1)]```

Answer (score 18):

As @thefourtheye already mentioned it is better to use `.filter` for your example.

However, if you want to remove an element by index using spread operator you can do the following:

```
let arrayOld = ['apple', 'orange', 'fig']
let index = 1;
let arrayNew = [...arrayOld.slice(0, index), ...arrayOld.slice(index + 1)];
console.log(arrayOld);
console.log(arrayNew);
```

Answer (score 13):

Why don't you filter it?

```
console.log(['apple', 'orange', 'fig'].filter(item => item !== 'orange'));
// [ 'apple', 'fig' ]
```

This returns a new array, with only the elements which satisfy the predicate function.

---

**Note:** This cannot be used as is to remove just one element, or only an element at a particular index. If that is the case, you can simply do it like this

```
var index = arrayOld.indexOf('orange')
console.log(arrayOld.filter((item, idx) => idx !== index));
```

The second parameter passed to the predicate function is the actual index of the element in the array.

Comment: Storing filtered indices would probably be cleaner than filtering with an index in mind `let indices = []; arr.filter((e, i) => {if (e === foo) {indices.push(i); return false;}return true;});`

Comment: Should be noted here that `filter` will scan the entire array, which unperformant with a large array, and isn't necessary if you actually have the index (for example, if you saved it off while building the array). In this case, answer provided by Oleksil is much better, as it runs in O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Well i had given some thought on this subject before since in functional JS some of the array methods are not well thought. So sometims they have to be tweaked a little bit... There are two issues

1. You shouldn't mutate what is not yours.
2. You should return something appropriate.

So for instance when deleting an item, depending on your use case you might want to pass the deleted item or the resulted array as an argument to a function while not mutating the original array. So in this particular case you have two options such as the one like you have mentioned

```
myFunction(myArr.slice(0,i).concat(a.slice(i+1))) // pass resulting array as argument
```

or another way to have the deleted item as result.

```
myFunction(a.slice().splice(i,1)[0]) // pass deleted item as an argument
```

Answer (score 1):

Destructuring might be what you are looking for

```
let [ a, ...b] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
console.log(a); // 'a'
console.log(b); // ['b', 'c'];
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment